# Simplexml_load_file not working suddenly PHP?

Tags: php, xml

All of my pages with the function simplexml_load_file suddenly are returning errors.
This has happened to ALL of the pages. Although i have touched any of the files, so it seems like its not the fault of something I did.

similar thing happened once before, and after one day it started working again on its own....

but now its happening again, any idea why?

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&responseencoding=XML&appid=AZFinish-d245-4297-83ae-a20a5f59ad23&siteid=0&version=661&IncludeSelector=Variations,TextDescription,Details,ItemSpecifics,ShippingCosts&&affiliate.networkId=9&affiliate.trackingId=5337310644&affiliate.customId=&ItemID=271478093658&outputSelector=GalleryInfo" in/home/oemfuelp/public_html/phantom-3.com/pagetc2.php on line 14

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: Couldn't resolve host name in /home/oemfuelp/public_html/phantom-3.com/pagetc2.php on line 200

Answer (score 0):

What you should try:

- check files read/write permission (though that's not likely the cause since you said you didn't change anything)
- If you have access to server files, check apache2 logs (post them here)
- do you have access to you server command line? If so check if it can resolve anything at all, maybe it's DNS problem. try pinging something inside of your server and outside.

  ```
  ping your_server_ip
  ping stackoverflow.com
  ```
- If pinging fails, that means something's wrong with your server. Contact your server admin.
- Lastly, it might not have anything  to do with what I mentioned above, if the resource that you're trying to load is faulty.